# The radiobutton selection not working in onCreate() method

Tags: android, radio-button, oncreate

I have two radiobuttons in activity. I am checking which radiobutton is selected in the onCreate method of the activity class by using the isChecked() method in two if conditions. The issue is that when I change the orientation of the device by tilting the device. The cheking is not working. In landscape orientation I selected the second radio button and when I tilted the device to portrait mode in the onCreate the control is going into the first if condition. ie,

```
if(rdo1.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "RadioButton1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Actually it should go to the second if condition:

```
if(rdo2.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "RadioButton2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What is the reason and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen it will directly goto onCreate method

If you already @Override the onConfigurationChanged() function in your java code( in your Android activity class) for handle Android Screen Orientation Change. Then your activity will never restart for any screen orientation changes. or you can close the orientation from the manifest by following code

```
    android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manifest..

```
 <activity android:name="Your Activity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

because when orientation changes that current activity is restarted that's why it happens.. try that above
 code..

Answer (score 0):

Try to manage focusable property of radio buttons in java.
or just make both radio buttons focusable="false";